# NodeJS babel-node build for production

Tags: node.js, babeljs

Okay, so I'm trying to deploy me NodeJS API to an AWS EC2 Instance. I used babel-node in the project, but now I'm having trouble building it. As the documentation states, babel-node should not be used for production.

> You should not be using babel-node in production. It is unnecessarily heavy, with high memory usage due to the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on the fly.

When I try to run the command `npm run babel-node src -d dist`

I keep getting the following error:

`` [DEP0062]: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` and `node --inspect-brk` instead. ``

Google has not been good to me and I haven't been able to figure out what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, my mistake and lack of research. Turns out `babel-node` should be used to run the actual nodejs app, `babel src -d dist`will transpile the code from src to dist folder